# Convert nonstandard date with short month to timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, date-conversion, date-parsing

I have unfortunetly a nonstandard date

```
Jul-23-2017
```

Is there any way to convert it to a unix timestamp in javascript?

Comment: `+(new Date("Jul-23-2017"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date("Jul-23-2017").getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you pass valid values to the date contructor, you can parse the date yourself

```js
var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var date   = "Jul-23-2017";
var parts  = date.split('-');
var unix   = (new Date(parts[2], months.indexOf(parts[0]), parts[1])).getTime();

console.log(unix)
```